# How to change dynamic radio button style when clicked

Tags: jquery, css, forms, radio-button

I am currently creating a dynamic pickup date form using radio buttons. I want to change the current selected value's style when user clicked on it. Here is my unsuccessful code:

```
foreach ($period as $day){
echo '<label class="pickup-date" id="pickupdate"><input type="radio" value="'.$day->format('M-d-Y').'" name="pickup_date">'.$day->format('M') . ' <span>' .$day->format('d') . '</span> '. $day->format('D') .'<br/></label>';
}
```

Css

```
.pickup-date-tab label.checked{
background: #6d1f89 !important;
color: #fff; }
```

jquery

```
$('#pickupdate').on('click',function(){
        $('#pickupdate').removeClass('checked');
        $(this).addClass('checked');
    });
```

My problem is, it is only works on the first button.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out, thanks to this website. I have found related problem.

I have updated the code to

```
foreach ($period as $day)
                {
                    echo '<label class="pickup-date" id="pickupdate"><input type="radio" value="'.$day->format('M-d-Y').'" name="pickup_date"><div class="highlited">'.$day->format('M') . ' <span>' .$day->format('d') . '</span> '. $day->format('D') .'</div></label>';

                }
```

The correct jquery for onclick

```
$(document).on('click','#deliverydate',function(){
    $('#pickupdate').removeClass('checked'); // i have removed this line instead I used CSS
    $(this).addClass('checked'); // i have removed this line instead I used CSS    });
```

Css

```
.pickup-date input[type=radio]:checked + .highlited{
    background: #6d1f89 !important;
    color: #fff;
}
```